# Receiving the Same MSMQ Message Twice?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq, message-queue

I have an MSMQ-based system with three layers that communicate with each other. For the sake of simplicity, I'll refer to them as Layer 1, 2, and 3. They sit like this:

```
Layer 1 <-> Layer 2 <-> Layer 3
```

So Layer 1 talks only to Layer 2, Layer 3 talks only to Layer 2, and Layer 2 talks to both others. I have four queues for this,

```
Layer1_in
Layer1_out
Layer3_out
Layer3_in
```

And the layers communicate over this infrastructure:

```
Layer 1 -> Layer1_out -> Layer 2
Layer 1 <- Layer1_in <- Layer 2
Layer 3 -> Layer3_out -> Layer 2
Layer 3 <- Layer3_in <- Layer 2
```

(sorry if this is more exhaustive than necessary)

Anyhow, a message gets passed from Layer 1 to Layer 2, some processing takes place, then another (related) message is sent to Layer 3, and vice versa. The issue I'm having is that occasionally I have two messages sent from Layer 1 to Layer 2, but instead of receiving both messages in order it's receiving the first message twice. I'm using `BeginReceive` on `Layer1_out` to asynchronously receive the message. When that completes I process the received message and call `BeginReceive` again to get the next message.

To track this down I implemented a message counter on the sending side and I write it to a text file. I'm using the `Extension` property to store a string representation of this message number so that I can then retrieve the message number on the processing side. When I recieve a message, I take this number and write it to a different file. This SHOULD produce two files that have the same contents, but instead I'll see things like

```
00000000000000000214
00000000000000000215
00000000000000000215 <- this is bad!
00000000000000000217
00000000000000000218
00000000000000000219
```

In the receipt log, indicating that message 215 was processed twice and 216 didn't come through. For my purposes it doesn't affect anything for me to process the same message twice (hence why this has gone unnoticed for some time), but missing a message altogether is a big problem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like Raymond Chen's recent post http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/05/22/9634511.aspx

Comment: @Ant: Interesting read, but I don't know that it has much influence on this issue as I'm not doing any explicit thread synchronization myself (there could be something done under the hood in the MSMQ libraries, but I have no control of or knowledge about that). Perhaps I'm missing something though...do you have an idea as to how this applies?

Comment: Do you have multiple threads sending / receiving data on either side? Perhaps one thread is overwriting another thread's data.

Comment: @Justin: Not explicitly, no. However, I think I may have discovered the issue; I'm currently testing and, assuming this fix works, I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved...figures that I would dole out multithreading advice one day then get bitten by a violation myself the next!

The culprit was this line:

```
receiveResult = <queueName>.BeginReceive()
```

When I had another message already waiting in the queue, my `ReceiveCompleted` event was firing on a different thread and getting to my `EndReceive(receiveResult)` call before the return value from `BeginReceive` was actually written to the `receiveResult` variable. As a result, I was calling `EndReceive` with the same value and getting the same message again! Locking the whole event handler around a sync object took care of the issue.

Comment: is `receiveResult` variable was shared between all threads? why you don't use [AsyncResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.receivecompletedeventargs.asyncresult.aspx) in [ReceiveCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue.receivecompleted.aspx) event arguments to end receiving?