# sending messages from one queue to other queues

Tags: c#, msmq

I'm using the code below to get all messages from a queue into an array and send to other queues also in an array, what's happening is it sends every message twice to every queue and I can't see why, can anyone see anything obvious?

thanks

```
public void SendToQs()
{
    Code.Class1 c = new Code.Class1();
    oInQueue = new MessageQueue(sInQueue);
    Message[] msgs = oInQueue.GetAllMessages();

    var queueArray = sOutQueues.Select(s => new MessageQueue(s)).ToArray();
    foreach (Message msg in msgs)
    {
        foreach (MessageQueue s in queueArray)
        {
            c.WriteMessage(s, msg, msg.Label);
        }

    }
    oInQueue.Purge();
}
```

WriteMessage:

```
public void WriteMessage(MessageQueue outputQueue, Message msg, string label)
{
    if (!outputQueue.Transactional)
    {
        try
        {
            outputQueue.Send(msg, label);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageQueueTransaction trans = new MessageQueueTransaction();
        try
        {
            trans.Begin();
            outputQueue.Send(msg, label, trans);
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("message Q exception" + ex.Message);
            trans.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So WriteMessage gets called X times but 2X messages are being sent?

Comment: exactly, been sticking in a few console.writelines and it seems to happen at the call.  Posted this incase I'd just been staring at it too long and there was something glaringly wrong which I can't see...

Comment: Would this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940351/receiving-the-same-msmq-message-twice?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, and it was a daft as I was expecting!
In my void Main() I had originally kicked off a process just to make sure it worked.
I then added a line to start a new thread with this process, forgetting to take the original one out, so it was running twice.
DOH!

Answer (score 0):

I have not had time to test this but you may want to consider this.

If a queue is having all it's messages sent to the other queues, then, when iterating through the list of queues - the original queue is also sent this message.

```
foreach (Message msg in msgs)
{
   foreach (MessageQueue s in queueArray)
   {
      if (s.Id == oInQueue.Id) continue; // Skip if this is the originator
      c.WriteMessage(s, msg, msg.Label);
   }
}
```